# Anchor to cover entire DIV - but with challenges and no javascript

Tags: css

I'm working on a little design challenge, and it's getting the better of me right now.

[image]

Essentially, it's a material design card, which means when I click it it takes me somewhere else.

The easy route would be (and as it is now) is to surround the content with an anchor. However, in this case I ONLY want the anchor text to be "My keyword".

Here's the simple html output:

```
<a class="post-card md-card">
    <div class="md-card-title aspect-16x9">
        <div class="title-large"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-card-content">
        <div class="sup-text"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

So, the 2 things I want to do are:

- Only have the keyword inside the anchor
- Be able click the whole thing (the link covers the entire outer div)

Here's the stuff that make it more difficult:

- The blue box on top has an aspect ratio set, which means its not a
  constant height
- The text inside the blue box is centered using Flexbox
- The white box isn't a fixed height either

Here's how the aspect ratio is calculated:

```
.AspectRatio(@widthRatio:16; @heightRatio:9; @useableWidth:100%) {
    &:extend(.clearfix all);
    
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:@useableWidth;

    &::before {
        content:"";
        float:left;
        padding-top:percentage(@heightRatio / @widthRatio);
    }
}
```

So I need to keep the keyword text where it is but make the whole thing clickable.

I've been playing around with the idea an absolutely positioned anchor on top, which I can do but I can't get it to stretch to the bottom without moving the text.

Any CSS gurus got some ideas?

Comment: so basically you really want to avoid just using a javascript to do a click for you and take the href from anchor ..

Comment: You want the whole thing to be clickable, but you don’t want the whole thing to be a link? Why? Those are kind of contradictory requirements.

Comment: @moped - yep, these links are specifically aimed at internal linking, so nothing is to get in the way.

Comment: @keithjgrant - they're not contradictory. I want to tell Google that the page is specifically about my "my keyword", with no extra bumff. As it's a material card with no extra functionality, ideally the whole thing shold be the clickable target.

Comment: @JohnOhara Oh interesting. Is that actually impacting your SEO?

Comment: A couple of things - at the moment we use similar combination links on the homepage - I have my suspicions because we're not sending a clear signal to what the page is about. However, as I said, the who reason for thsi set of links is to up the anti on our internal linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a good starting place...

```css
.post-card {
  background-color: #63d9ff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.post-card * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.post-card .md-card-title {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}

.post-card .md-card-title .content-prop,
.post-card .md-card-title .content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.post-card .md-card-title .content-prop {
  padding-top: 56%;
  width: 0;
}

.post-card .md-card-title .content {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.post-card .space-prop {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56%;
}

.md-card-content {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-card md-card">
    <a class="md-card-title aspect-16x9" href="#">
        <span class="content-prop"></span><!--
        --><span class="content">My Keyword</span>
    </a>
    <span class="space-prop"></span>
    <div class="md-card-content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In quis mauris ut eros consectetur efficitur vitae at leo.
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp8v7jxy/1/)

So the explaination...

The whole post card is positioned relative, the anchor is then positioned absolute within it. The anchor is given a top, left, bottom, and right value of 0 which makes it cover it's parent container.

The content-prop and space-prop are given no height but have a top padding of 56%. This means that their top-padding value is 56% of their width which works out at a 16:9 ratio. The space banner is used here to add a empty gap at the top of the post card to make room for the anchor.

Both the content-prop and the content elements are set to display inline-block and vertical aligned to middle. Because the prop is taller than the content, the content floats in the centre. The HTML comment between these two elements eliminates white space so that the content div can be set to 100% width even when the prop is on the same horizontal row.

Comment: Lol, guess what Michael? I've just come up with the identical solution. However, as you have already posted and I know this code works, I'll accept this answer.